# dropdown form disappears on mouse click

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

I have a form in my dropdown which disappears on click
 I tried the jquery

```
 $(function() {
                  // Fix input element click problem
                  $('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function (e)
                  {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                  });
            });
```

but this din't solve my problem
Here is my code

```
<li class="dropdown" style="float:right">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="text-decoration:none">
<img src="img/button.png" style="float:right;"/>
</a> 
<ul class="dropdown-menu">               
    <form action="" method="post">
    <li>
        <input type="text" class="input-large" id="name" name="name"/>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
        <input type="password" class="input-large " id="pass" name="pass"/>
    </li><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</ul>
</li>
```

have used bootstrap.min.js .I just included the js file in my application and here is the code for the dropdown

```
{
    function d()
    {
       a(b).parent().removeClass("open")
    }"use strict";
    var b='[data-toggle="dropdown"]',c=function(b)
    {
    var c=a(b).on("click.dropdown.data-api",this.toggle);
    a("html").on("click.dropdown.data-api",function()
    {
    c.parent().removeClass("open")
    }
    )
    };
    c.prototype={
    constructor:c,toggle:function(b)
    {
    var c=a(this),e=c.attr("data-target"),f,g;
    return e||(e=c.attr("href"),e=e&&e.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/,"")),f=a(e),f.length||(f=c.parent()),g=f.hasClass("open"),d(),!g&&f.toggleClass("open"),!1
    }
    },a.fn.dropdown=function(b)
    {
    return this.each(function()
    {
    var d=a(this),e=d.data("dropdown");
    e||d.data("dropdown",e=new c(this)),typeof b=="string"&&e[b].call(d)})},a.fn.dropdown.Constructor=c,a(function(){a("html").on("click.dropdown.data-api",d),a("body").on("click.dropdown.data-api",b,c.prototype.toggle)
    }
    )
    }
```

Comment: Put your code on a jsfiddle so we know the exact behavior. Also try to add more details on your issue.

Comment: what do you mean disappears??? do you have any other event handlers for its parent.. if yes posting that too wil be helpful

Comment: You probably have some event handler bound to the dropdown menu which hides the menu on click of it' child items. Can we see how the dropdown is done?